# Solutions to create HTML based slide shows

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, slideshow

What solutions are available to create HTML-based slides?
A while ago I saw a demo of an fantasy solution that transition between slides was like some image on the table a camera zoom out and zoom in to another slide, but now I do not remember its name.

Comment: As opposed to exporting your PowerPoint presentation to HTML format?

Comment: @iglvzx Yes. I am looking for a output.

Comment: I do not understand. PowerPoint allows you to export/save your presentation in HTML format so it can be viewed within a web browser, without any additional software. Can you edit your question to clarify exactly what it is you are looking to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Use Prezi, I used it in college and it was sweet!  Way more interactive then powerpoint.

[Prezi](http://prezi.com/)